# dvipdfm OR dvipdfmx OR dvipdft?

Tags: texstudio, dvipdfmx, dvipdf

I freshly installed LaTeX on my computer using the `ProTeXt` bundle. I was able to install everything smoothly, but the program `TexStudio` didn't auto-configure, like the manual said it would. Using `Options>>Configure TexStudio>>Commands` I was able to set pointers to most commands, except for `dvipdf`. I have three choices with regards to the executable for `dvipdf` (listed in the title of this question). Which one should I choose?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short answer: `dvipdfmx`.

Longer answer: `dvipdfmx` is an extension of `dvipdfm`, enabling access to more PDF-specific features. As such, it implements a superset of the features of `dvipdfm`, and is more powerful. `dvipdft` is a tool to use `dvipdfm` to make thumbnails (according to `texdoc dvipdft`). As such, it's not what you want at all!

Comment: BTW, in current TeXLive, `dvipdfm` **is** `dvipdfmx` running in a compatibility mode.

Comment: There is `dvipdf` that's part of the Ghostscript distribution, but it's surely inferior to `dvipdfmx`.