# dvipdfm.def not found

Tags: errors, dvipdf

Recently, I had to flash my hard drive and reinstall the operating systems. I chose to install Ubuntu 13.10. However, when I compile my LaTeX document, I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `dvipdfm.def' not found.
```

My .tex document uses the following header:

```
\documentclass[dvipdfm]{sig-alternate}
```

The `cls` file comes from ACM website. I was wondering how I can fix this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I downloaded the example from the [ACM website](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates#aL2), and reproduced your problem compiling on Ubuntu 13.10 using the `dvipdfm` option to the document class.  I had a similar problem with my thesis template.

The problem is that `dvipdfm` has been replaced by `dvipdfmx` in the newest versions of texlive and Ubuntu.  The `dvipdfmx` package extends `dvipdfm` with support for unicode. Unfortunately, it doesn't include a backwards compatible `dvipdfm.def`. Your problem should be fixed by replacing the document class option `dvipdfm` with `dvipdfmx`:

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{sig-alternate}
```

Further info on `dvipdfm` v. `dvipdfmx`:

[dvipdfm OR dvipdfmx OR dvipdft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73783/dvipdfm-or-dvipdfmx-or-dvipdft)

http://tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2005-November/018933.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd experienced with same problem. I tried to make these steps for solving this issue.

1. I downloaded the `dvipdfmx.def` file (i.e.
   http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/dvipdfmx-def/dvipdfmx.def)
2. Copy this file to `/etc/texmf/dvipdfrmx/` directory OR you can keep it
   in directory with your `.dvi` file.

This solution works in Linux Mint 16 Petra.