# Convert DVI into PDF properly

Tags: pdf, colortbl, dvi, convert

For viewing my work when I'm programming LaTeX, I decided to use the DVI format.
The reason is that the result is perfect compare to the PDF.

For example, the borders of tabulars appear perfeclty even if I use `rowcolors` or other exotic stuf. It doesnt in PDF. Even if I'm zooming-in, sometimes it doesnt show up.

But my main issue with that is that I need to be able to generate a document to distribute to all my collegues. The PDF format is mainly known and used.
So I would like to generate a PDF from the DVI.

I have this option on TeXnicCenter, but the result is almost the same that with the direct conversion in PDF.
Is there a way to generate a PDF from a DVI that look exactly the same ?

Is there another option of all this ?

Comment: There's `dvipdf`, `dvipdfm`, and `dvipdfmx` to convert `.dvi` files to `.pdf` the latter being, _I think_, the evolution of the former two (yes, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73820/134574).

Comment: Others might like to see examples of the issues you have with `rowcolors` and viewers. I don't think many go about the regular dvi route anymore.

Comment: My version of TeXnicCenter uses `dvipdfm` as default, but the result is still different than with the DVI format.

Comment: @joseldsm They are different formats. You can't expect them to be identical.

Comment: @daleif, yes you might be right. But it seems really inconvenient to not have proper results with some basics LaTeX packages and fonctions.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I understand that, but my question was more about if there is any way to "freeze" the render of the DVI format and convert it in PDF.

Comment: @joseldsm The conversion should respect the document _properties_. The rendering is done by the viewer (I have a pdf viewer that shows the dvi pixelated, and another which shows basically the same as the pdf). Try another viewer for both pdf and dvi to see if there's a difference. Also, show what problems are you having with `rowcolors`, so we can check too.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you for your help. Well, while using `rowcolor` or `cellcolor`, the `clines` doesnt show up. But I think I can find explanations and solutions on the Internet about this matter. My main issue is that I'm having different issues like this with the PDF format, that's why I wanted to see if there was a solution by using the DVI format.

Comment: Which pdf viewer do you use? Maybe it would be easier to replace it with a better working one than to make the dvi detour.

Comment: What you ask isn't possible because the disappearing rules are a property of the pdf viewer being used, not of the pdf file.

Comment: In the case of clines, that is user error the colortbl documentation makes it explicit that clines do not work with coloured backgrounds.

Comment: @samcarter I have no idea. When I open the PDF convert parameters, there is nothing indicated in the preprocessor and postprocessor categories. (I'm using TeXnicCenter)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your help. I found a solution using the `hhline` package for that. But why is it working with the DVI format then ? And it was just an example amoug other issues I'm having. I'm sure there is good alternatives to make all work with the PDF format, but I was just curious to know if there were a solution with the DVI format, since this format is more convenient for the way I'm going with my work.

Comment: you don't need to "find" that solution the colortbl doc says that is what to use:-)

Comment: I just posted an answer but the differences are unrelated to DVI/PDF it's just that the different formats force you to use different viewers, you would see similar difference using two different dvi viewers or two different pdf viewers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two separate issues with tabular rules and colortbl colored backgrounds.

1. `\cline` doesn't work. This is explicitly documented in the `colortbl` manual. `\cline` is implemented such that it takes no vertical space, the rule is a negative space of half the width followed by a rule followed by another negative space of half the width. So if there are coloured backgrounds, The top half of the `\cline` over-prints the background of the row above, and the bottom half of the `\cline` is over-printed by the background of the row below.
2. Vertical rules and horiziontal rules may vanish at some zoom levels. In the DVI or PDF the coloured panels and rules are specified to very high accuracy as adjacent rules, however a viewing application always needs to snap such coordinates on to the physical pixel layout of the device, so it can happen that the coloured panels either side of a rule due to rounding end up on adjacent or nearly adjacent pixels and so making the rule impossibly thin to see. Some viewers are better at avoiding this than others, it is a property of the viewer, not of the format.

A better way to solve this is *not* to draw the rules *between* the coloured panels but to render the table in two or three  layers with the coloured panels first, then the data and the rules. That requires two passes over the table though and just isn't the way `colortbl` works. There are answers on site showing tikz-decorated tables that work this way and so are more robust with respect to pixel rounding in viewers.

Comment: using rules and coloured backgrounds usually makes an ugly table anyway so another less technical way of avoiding the problem is: don't use rules with coloured tables.

Comment: I finally decided to use `matrix of nodes` with `tikzpicture`. Works perfectly with PDF and DVI even if it's a little bit more complicated to build tables and to get infos about how to do stuff. Thank you @DavidCarlisle.